# Cannot set navigation bar background color to white on Android

Tags: android, cordova

I'm  unable to set the navigation bar to a white background. Every other color works, but when I set it to white, it's displayed as a dark grey on my phone.

I'm using Cordova and compiling the apk with SDK 29. I have created a plugin myself that uses `setNavigationBarColor` and explicitly passes `Color.WHITE` as a param but I get a dark grey navigation bar color.

As I mentioned, other colors work perfectly fine and I can even set the navigation bar to transparent. Is there anything I'm missing? Are there any flags in specific I need to set?
I'm sure it's not something particular with my phone, as the Google Rewards app, for instance, is able to do this

Here's the piece of code I'm using based on: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window#setNavigationBarColor(int)

```java
final Window window = cordova.getActivity().getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
window.setNavigationBarColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just migrated to Capacitor and used this plugin: https://github.com/nikosdouvlis/capacitor-navigationbar/tree/master/src